# Geometric proof on three colinear points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

The following question consists of a final exam, which is originally written in Spanish, so please excuse me if something is lost in traslation.
The problem goes as follows: We start of with a rhombus ABCD counterclockwise, where we define point P variable on the diagonal AC. We are then defined point Q as the intersection between the circumscribed circles of ABP and CDP. We are asked to prove that D,Q and B are colinear, in other words, that Q belongs to the diagonal CD.

Ive tried to tackle the problem through congruent triangles, or angles and paralel lines, but I cant seem to notice were to make the breakthrough to the solution. The only major conclusion until now is that triangle BPD is isosceles.

Comment: The diagonal is $BD$, not $CD$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Will $\angle 1 = \angle 2 =\angle 3$?

[image]

(2) Wll $\angle red = 90^0 - \angle 2 = 90^0 - \angle 3 = \angle purple$?

(3) Will the green marked angles equal?

If the answers are all yes, then you have all the necessary ingredients.